# Bootstrap 4 - Inline List?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I migrated a site from Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 to Bootstrap 4 Beta 1.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav list-inline">
  <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">FB</a></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">G+</a></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">T</li>
</ul>
```

Now, the items align vertically instead of horizontally. How do I create an inline list with the Bootstrap 4 beta?

Answer (score 101):

[Bootstrap4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/typography/#inline)

Remove a list’s bullets and apply some light **margin** with a combination of two classes, **.list-inline** and **.list-inline-item.**

```
<ul class="list-inline">
   <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">FB</a></li>
   <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">G+</a></li>
   <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">T</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works in Bootstrap 5 also. Less is more, `list-inline` as ul class is functionally not needed.

Answer (score 15):

The html code you written is absolutely perfect

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav list-inline">
 <li class="list-inline-item">FB</li>
 <li class="list-inline-item">G+</li>
 <li class="list-inline-item">T</li>
 </ul>
```

The reasons that could be possible is 
1. Check out the CSS for class name "nav" or "navbar-nav" may be over writing it, try to remove and debug the class names in the **ul** element.
2. Check any of the child element(**a** tag or "social-icon" class) is using block level CSS style
3. Check out your using a HTML5 **!DOCTYPE html** 
4. Place your bootstrap.css link at the last before closing your head tag 
5. Change **text-xs-center** to **text-center** because **xs** is dropped in Bootstrap 4.

This One will work perfectly fine

```
<!-- Use this inside Head tag-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<!-- Use this inside Body tag-->
<div  class="container">
<ul class="list-inline">
<li class="list-inline-item"><a class="social-icon text-center" target="_blank" href="#">FB</a></li>
<li class="list-inline-item"><a class="social-icon text-center" target="_blank" href="#">G+</a></li>
<li class="list-inline-item"><a class="social-icon text-center" target="_blank" href="#">T</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

**Inline**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<ul class="list-inline">
  <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">FB</a></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">G+</a></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">T</a></li>
</ul>
```

and learn more about  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/#inline

Answer (score 4):

**.list-inline class in bootstrap is a Inline Unordered List.**

> If you want to create a horizontal menu using ordered or unordered
> list you need to place all list items in a single line i.e. side by
> side. You can do this by simply applying the class

```
<div class="list-inline">
    <a href="#" class="list-inline-item">First item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-inline-item">Secound item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-inline-item">Third item</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: While this might solve the original question, it's best to include a description so we know what is going on.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't it be just the `.list-group`? See below,

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item active">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Reference: [Bootstrap 4 Basic Example of a List group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/#basic-example)